# Homebrew install node - make taking too long

Tags: macos, node.js, compiler-construction, clang, homebrew

Should it take forever to install node.js using Homebrew? I've attempted several times, even leaving it running overnight, and it has never completed. I'm doing it again now in verbose mode, and it's printing endless 'clang' lines. It's not erroring out, but am I doing something wrong, or should I just use the package installer?

Running OS X 10.8 on a Retina MacBook Pro (2.4 GHz, 16 GB RAM)

Comment: After letting it run for a while it appears to be stalled on this: touch /private/tmp/node-9Vum/node-v0.10.22/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/v8.stamp

Comment: Sounds like something is broken there, though not sure what. Make sure your homebrew and XCode are up to date, but in the mean time if you want to go about your work, install from the joyent packages.

Comment: Apart from the building apparently being broken, I've seen multiple reports of Homebrew-installed Node's that were giving the user grief (`npm` giving strange errors, packages not being found, etc). Why not use the official Node.js Mac installer?